# Unable to install spacy 2.1.9 on google colab with python 3.10

Tags: dependencies, google-colaboratory, spacy, python-3.10, allennlp

Recently I was using google colab when it ws on python 3.9. I need to work on spacy version 2.1.9 which has become incompatible with new version. Using fallback runtime also giving me the same installation issue.

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement spacy==2.1.7.dev0 (from versions: 0.31, 0.32, 0.33, 0.40, 0.51, 0.52, 0.60, 0.61, 0.62, 0.63, 0.64, 0.65, 0.67, 0.68, 0.70, 0.80, 0.81, 0.82, 0.83, 0.84, 0.85, 0.86, 0.87, 0.88, 0.89, 0.90, 0.91, 0.92, 0.93, 0.94, 0.95, 0.97, 0.98, 0.99, 0.100.0, 0.100.1, 0.100.2, 0.100.3, 0.100.4, 0.100.5, 0.100.6, 0.100.7, 0.101.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.0.3, 1.0.4, 1.0.5, 1.1.0, 1.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.2.0, 1.3.0, 1.4.0, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.6.0, 1.7.0, 1.7.1, 1.7.2, 1.7.3, 1.7.5, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.9.0, 1.10.0, 1.10.1, 2.0.0, 2.0.1.dev0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2.dev0, 2.0.2, 2.0.3.dev0, 2.0.3, 2.0.4.dev0, 2.0.4, 2.0.5.dev0, 2.0.5, 2.0.6.dev0, 2.0.6, 2.0.7, 2.0.8, 2.0.9, 2.0.10.dev0, 2.0.10, 2.0.11.dev0, 2.0.11, 2.0.12.dev0, 2.0.12.dev1, 2.0.12, 2.0.13.dev0, 2.0.13.dev1, 2.0.13.dev2, 2.0.13.dev4, 2.0.13, 2.0.14.dev0, 2.0.14.dev1, 2.0.15, 2.0.16.dev0, 2.0.16, 2.0.17.dev0, 2.0.17.dev1, 2.0.17, 2.0.18.dev0, 2.0.18.dev1, 2.0.18, 2.1.0, 2.1.1.dev0, 2.1.1, 2.1.2, 2.1.3, 2.1.4, 2.1.5, 2.1.6, 2.1.7.dev0, 2.1.7, 2.1.8, 2.1.9, 2.2.0.dev10, 2.2.0.dev11, 2.2.0.dev13, 2.2.0.dev15, 2.2.0.dev17, 2.2.0.dev18, 2.2.0.dev19, 2.2.0, 2.2.1, 2.2.2.dev0, 2.2.2.dev4, 2.2.2, 2.2.3.dev0, 2.2.3, 2.2.4, 2.3.0.dev1, 2.3.0, 2.3.1, 2.3.2, 2.3.3.dev0, 2.3.3, 2.3.4, 2.3.5, 2.3.6, 2.3.7, 2.3.8, 2.3.9, 3.0.0, 3.0.1.dev0, 3.0.1, 3.0.2, 3.0.3, 3.0.4, 3.0.5, 3.0.6, 3.0.7, 3.0.8, 3.0.9, 3.1.0, 3.1.1, 3.1.2, 3.1.3, 3.1.4, 3.1.5, 3.1.6, 3.1.7, 3.2.0, 3.2.1, 3.2.2, 3.2.3, 3.2.4, 3.2.5, 3.3.0.dev0, 3.3.0, 3.3.1, 3.3.2, 3.4.0, 3.4.1, 3.4.2, 3.4.3, 3.4.4, 3.5.0, 3.5.1, 3.5.2, 3.6.0.dev0, 4.0.0.dev0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for spacy==2.1.7.dev0
```

I only need these versions of spacy (<2.2,>=2.1.0) as allennlp 0.9.0 works only with this version.

I tried installing every spacy version from 2.1.0 to 2.1.9 and all of them incompatible.

Comment: If you can bring down the version of your python to `3.6` or `3.7`?